# Using AWS S3 cli to prune files by age?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

**My use case:**

I'm using an s3 folder to upload/download a bunch of small (~2kB) files. Each file has unique contents and the file names are a hash of the contents. There are no time/datestamps in the file names. About 1-3 times per day, I run a script that builds a new one of these files and uses the AWS S3 CLI to upload it to the folder. The files are then used by an app.

However, the number of files is getting close to 1000, and I've identified that I could prune the oldest 20-30% every month and the app would be fine.

**Question**:

I want to write a script that can sort the files in the s3 folder by upload/modify date, and then delete the oldest n files or oldest m% of files. What is the most efficient way to do this using the AWS S3 CLI?

I'd like to avoid using pagination or anything involving manually doing stuff in the AWS web console.

Comment: The easiest solution is to setup a lifecycle rule on the bucket itself to delete objects older than x days.

Comment: I would write a Lambda function using one of the supported SDKs so i have full control over the logic.

Comment: setup up a cron job with lifecycle bucket policies as per other comments to automate eveything

Answer (score 2):

Second what Anon Coward has commented above - easiest way is through bucket lifecycle. If you don't want to interact with the AWS console you can do this through the cli with:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket mybucketname --lifecycle-configuration file://myconffile.json
```

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle.html